# most efficient way to check if a string is within a wordlist

Tags: c++

I need the most efficient way to determine whether a string is in a wordlist (this is a textfile of all words).

Obviously I could create an ofstream object and loop through each line to see whether the string is present.

Is there a quicker way? Perhaps by using a map?

Thanks

Comment: What is your 'string' - can it be anything more than a simple word? And if so, would that mean there is no way it *can* be in your word list? If so, the first check would be in the entire string for "illegal" characters, and if present you don't need to test against your entite list.

Comment: No, there will be no strings with illegal characters.

Comment: So, are you searching for `{"beer", "wine", "horse", "kingdom", "to", "be" ... }` in Shakespeare's works, or are you checking if the words in a short essay are also in Shakespeare's work, or if a short list (a few dozen) words are in an essay?

Comment: Then what is the difference between "string" and "word"? Are you using these two terms interchangeably?

Comment: I'm essentially checking whether a random combination of characters (a-z) is a word (i.e. is present in the wordlist).

Comment: If you are searching for whole words, a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` of words should work. If you are searching for string within the words, I don't think there is any efficient method.

Comment: @Jongware - Sorry by word I mean an English word (in the dictionary)

Comment: So, basically, you generate a random number for length, then generate that many random letters `a-z` and then want to know if it's an actual word?

Comment: @MatsPetersson - That's a simplification but essentially yes.

Comment: Order the word list in a binary tree. Looking up any word is then basically as fast as technically possible. (Ah - while thinking how to implement that: just sort the word list and use a binary search!)

Comment: `std::set` would be more effective than a map. A map is used to map a key to a value, but your word list is merely a set of values. `std::unordered_set` would provide even faster lookups. Of course, there are even more efficient ways to do it, but they may require a lot of implementation work. How much work are you willing to expend on this problem? Does it really need to be the "most efficient" solution or just "efficient enough"?

Comment: @Jongware Certainly there are faster ways to check if an item is in a set. See: hash tables. If probabilistic results are acceptable, see: bloom filter. It all depends on the problem and what guarantees are required.

Comment: Thanks - what about if we are only looking to see if a string is a subset of a word?

Comment: @user3457175 That is a lot harder to do quickly. Simplest solution is to loop through each word in the list and call `.find()` on each. There is no easy way to make it faster than that.

Comment: If by subset of a word, you mean "some part of the word", then yes, you have to scan every word to see if some part matches another part. If you mean "starts the same", you can use `std::set` or some other ordered container and use `lower_bound` to find the nearest before, then iterate until `upper_bound` (nearest after) of your target word [assuming more than one character]. I'm sure there are various ways to build tables of sub-strings, but for a reasonable size dictionary it gets very large rather quickly (e.g /usr/share/dict/words is 480k lines -> millions of substrings)

Comment: @Mats Petersson thanks that's very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a particular word in a list of many words, I would use a `std::unordered_set`, which is a hash-table by another name.

Basically:

1. Read words from file into set.
2. Pick a "random combination of letters".
3. use `find()` to see if it's in the set.
4. Go to 2 as required.

Obviously, if you only want to search for a single word, it's no point in loading into a set. Just read the file and check as you go (because on average you'll only need to read half the file, which is obviously about 50% faster than reading the whole file)